# Regular Expression matching every character except <,>,",/,\

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a JavaScript regular expression to match a string containing any possible character (including spaces) except any of the following five special characters `<,>,",/,\`. I have tried using `^` inside `[]` which skips matching the characters inside `[]` such as `/[^<>""\\/]/` but this doesn't seem to work as expected

Comment: Please post actual code using actual examples. Hit the `<>` snippet editor and supply a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You almost did it, use this: `/^[^<>"\/\\]*$/`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/s7DEKm/1.